# Javascript on click set input before ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have three inputs in the following form. Two inputs type is `text` and another one input type is `hidden`. Now when I click the submit button then two input values need to set the hidden input before run the ajax query. Because, ajax will get the data from the hidden input only. I have tried it myself but, it's not working for me. Now, when I click the submit ajax working first then set the both values to hidden input.

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="date" value="2018-11-09">
<input type="text" class="time" value="15:00:00">
<input type="hidden" class="date-time" value="">
<button type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried that did not work.  Also show us the logic that is doing the ajax.

Comment: `$('.date-time').val(whatever_value_you_want);` if you make sure to have a logic around that before calling your AJAX function, you will set the value of the hidden input field. Now, without further information and code it will be impossible to help you any further as we have absolutely *zero* clue about your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the following code I am assuming that the 'Submit' button has its type changed to 'submit' as this will give you more control of when the form is submitted:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault(); // stop the form from automatically submitting

  $('.date-time').val($('.date').val() + $('.time').val());

  console.log($('input[type=hidden').val());

  // call your ajax here

});
```

The important line here for your question is:

```
  $('.date-time').val($('.date').val() + $('.time').val());
```

This sets the value of the input .date-time to the input of .date and .time, although I would recommend using ids instead of classes as they are unique